# Intento reducir una cadena de caracteres obtenidos por medio de un lector de QR

Tags: android

**Este  es  el código  con la que   intento reducirlo**

```
    String  valor;

   et1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etCodigoAddProducto);
    String valor=et1.getText().toString();
    et1.setText(valor.substring(20,34));
```

**El logcat me  dice  que  mi error  es aquí**

```
             et1.setText(valor.substring(20,34));
```

**Error que  m muestra  el logcat**

```
     --------- beginning of crash
      11-23 17:37:17.701 2840-2840/com.example.aceraspire.fujitsu_mysql 
         E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                Process: com.example.aceraspire.fujitsu_mysql, PID: 2840
                                                                                java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.aceraspire.fujitsu_mysql/com.example.aceraspire.fujitsu_mysql.AddProducto}: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=0; index=8
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2817)
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2892)
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1593)
                                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
                                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
                                                                                 Caused by: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=0; index=8
                                                                                    at java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1971)
                                                                                    at com.example.aceraspire.fujitsu_mysql.AddProducto.onCreate(AddProducto.java:82)
                                                                                    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6975)
                                                                                    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1213)
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2770)
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2892) 
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0) 
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1593) 
                                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105) 
                                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541) 
                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240) 
                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767) 
  11-23 17:37:17.704 1674-2814/? W/ActivityManager:   Force finishing activity com.example.aceraspire.fujitsu_mysql/.AddProducto
 11-23 17:37:17.707 1674-2814/? W/ActivityManager:   Force finishing activity com.example.aceraspire.fujitsu_mysql/.mymenu
11-23 17:37:17.716 1674-1691/? I/ActivityManager: Showing crash dialog for package com.example.aceraspire.fujitsu_mysql u0
11-23 17:37:17.725 1403-2017/? E/SurfaceFlinger: ro.sf.lcd_density must be defined as a build property
11-23 17:37:17.726 1674-4291/? D/OpenGLRenderer: HWUI GL Pipeline
11-23 17:37:17.758 1394-1394/? D/gralloc_ranchu: gralloc_alloc: Creating ashmem region of size 2654208
```

Comment: Hola Sofia, recuerda que si desarrollas en Android y no usas el LogCat vas a perder mucho tiempo tratando de encontrar un problema, no olvides agregar siempre el mensaje de error desplegado en el mismo, un saludo!

Comment: Pon el mensaje que te retorna el LogCat, lo más probable es que tengas una excepción al momento de obtener el substring debido a que la cantidad de caracteres de tu String sea menor que 34

Comment: @diegoveloper también podría ser que no existe el elemento con id etCodigoAddProducto en el layout, como bien comentas es necesario el mensaje de error en el LogCat o que agregue su layout.

Comment: no creo porque entonces, el error sería aquí  String valor=et1.getText().toString(); , debido a que et1 sería nulo

Comment: @diegoveloper    la  cantidad  de  caracteres de  mi String   si es mayor a 34 y  si  existe el id  etCodigoAddProducto   es no es  el error.

Comment: y podrías poner el detalle del LogCat, creo que eso ayudaría bastante, sino solo estamos haciendo suposiciones

Comment: @Jorgesys  el  el layout  si existe el id  etCodigoAddProducto

Comment: @Sofia como comenta Diego, en este caso es importante revisar que sucede en el LogCat, de lo contrarío solo suponemos pero no sabemos la realidad del error.

Comment: Ahora que releo el problema, parece que el error es porque tiene una variable global como "valor",  y dentro del método vuelve a declarar una variable local con el mismo nombre "valor" ,  String valor=et1.getText().toString(); ,   es posible que al usar esta línea :  et1.setText(valor.substring(20,34)); , el valor que tome sea el global? por eso estaría vacío y sale la excepción.

Comment: @Jorgesys acabo  de  agregar  el logcat agradeceré   muchisimo  que lo revises  y  me puedas  ayudar a  resolver mi error

Comment: @diegoveloper acabo  de  agregar  el logcat agradeceré   muchisimo  que lo revises  y  me puedas  ayudar a  resolver mi error.

Comment: ya te dije la respuesta: 

Ahora que releo el problema, parece que el error es porque tiene una variable global como "valor", y dentro del método vuelve a declarar una variable local con el mismo nombre "valor" , String valor=et1.getText().toString(); , es posible que al usar esta línea : et1.setText(valor.substring(20,34)); , el valor que tome sea el global? por eso estaría vacío y sale la excepción.

Comment: @Sofia pues en realidad era ese el problema la longitud es mucho menor por lo tanto no podrá cortar la cadena.

Comment: claro era obvio :) , solo que está leyendo el valor de una variable vacía, cambiale el nombre:   String value=et1.getText().toString(); et1.setText(value.substring(20,34));   y asegurate de que ese edittext tenga datos

Comment: @Sofia es importante saber como obtienes el codigo al leer el QR, este segmento de código debe de ejecutarse cuando se obtiene la cadena, esto es muy importante. Si lo obtienes por ejemplo en onCreate() el valor de tu EditText siempre será un valor vacio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sofia, el valor dentro de la variable `valor` puede no tener la longitud que intentas obtener, en este caso 34, si no la tiene obtendrías un IndexOutOfBoundsException,

como se muestra en el LogCat:

> Caused by: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=0;
>   index=8

te recomiendo validar de esta forma para evitar el error:

```
String valor = et1.getText().toString();

if(valor.isEmpty() && valor.length()>=34){
       //Reduce la cadena.
     valor = et1.setText(valor.substring(20,34));           
  }else{
       //la longitud no es mayor o igual a 34, no podrá reducir la cadena.
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  String  valor; // Tienes una variable global aquí

   et1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etCodigoAddProducto);
```

Declaras una variable valor aquí nuevamente, que es la variable del método,

```
   String valor=et1.getText().toString();
    et1.setText(valor.substring(20,34));
```

Probablemente esté tomando el "valor" de la variable global que es vacío.

```
  et1.setText(valor.substring(20,34));
```

De todas maneras asegurate que ese EditText (et1) tenga datos.

Answer (score 0):

No se esta capturando el valor correcto y/o el valor no cuenta con 34 dígitos .. esto es según la condición que pones para poder reducir el tamaño del mismo valor.

```
 et1.setText(valor.substring(20,34));
```

recuerda que el substring funciona de la siguiente manera. (usando tus datos)

de todo el texto (valor) solo se obtiene una porción  a partir del 20 dígito hasta el dígito 34

donde si o si el texto (valor) debe de tener 34 dígitos como mínimo.

puedes realizar una condición if para poder validar si el texto (valor) tiene 43 dígitos o mas..

String valor = et1.getText().toString();

```
if(valor.isEmpty() && valor.length()>=34){
     valor = et1.setText(valor.substring(20,34));           
  }else{
       //el texto (valor) no cumple la condición, el texto tiene menos de 34 dígitos
  }
```